# Kill All Spawned Chromes

Tags: c#, process, dependencies

I have a project that has the following methods.

```
using System.Management;

        public void KillAllSpawnedChromes() {
            var chromeProcs = GetMyChildChromeProcesses();

            _logger.Info("Found {0} chrome processess still running. Killing them", chromeProcs.Count());
            foreach (var chromeProc in chromeProcs) {
                chromeProc.Kill();
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Process> GetMyChildChromeProcesses() {
            var myCurrentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            var children = new List<Process>();
            var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                $"Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID={myCurrentProcess.Id}");

            foreach (var o in mos.Get()) {
                var mo = (ManagementObject)o;
                children.Add(Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])));
            }

            return children.Where(x => x.ProcessName.Contains("chrome"));
        }
    }
```

I would like to delete this dependency from System.Managment. Is there any other way to kill Chrome processes?

Comment: How do you want to kill the Chrome processes? Using a command line?

Comment: No, I would like to know if there is an alternative to the methods that I described

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following [Extension Method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/extension-method-in-C-Sharp/):

```
//  from https://code-examples.net/en/q/60640
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    private static string FindIndexedProcessName(int pid)
    {
        try
        {
            var processName = Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName;
            var processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            string processIndexdName = null;

            for (var index = 0; index < processesByName.Length; index++)
            {
                processIndexdName = index == 0 ? processName : processName + "#" + index;
                var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);
                if ((int)processId.NextValue() == pid)
                {
                    return processIndexdName;
                }
            }

            return processIndexdName;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static Process FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(string indexedProcessName)
    {
        try
        {
            var parentId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", indexedProcessName);
            return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId.NextValue());
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Process Parent(this Process process)
    {
        return FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(FindIndexedProcessName(process.Id));
    }
}
```

The kill loop is now rather simple:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
int pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

foreach (Process process in processes)
{
   var parent = process.Parent();

   if ((parent != null) && (pid == parent.Id))
   {
       process.Kill();
   }
}
```

Note that a single instance of the *Chrome* browser usually spawns several processes. It might be necessary to kill them or properly shut them down in a specific order. Unforeseen damage of the *Chrome* data files might happen, unless you are careful.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.

var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);

Threw this exception:

"Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry."

Comment: I've added some exception handling. Does it work for you now?